# eBay API GetSearchResults call returns 'Undefined property: SoapFault::$SearchResultItemArray' error

Tags: php, ebay-api

I have a project where i need to access a product list from EBay based on a keyword search, i am familiar with apis so i am just trying to get my head around ebays.

Ok so far i started by signing up for a Ebay developer login all done have all my ID's keys etc.

Headed over to https://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/eBay/documentation-tools/code-sample/219177 and downloaded the PHP code sample as this is the one i am going to be using.

Ok so entered all my details and the call i want to run is GetSearchResults.

Everytime i run this command i get the error below.

```
Undefined property: SoapFault::$SearchResultItemArray
```

Can any help me with this or can they point me in the right direction of a working php sdk that i can use to get a display of search results?

Here is the code taken from ebay developer https://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/eBay/documentation-tools/code-sample/219177

```
<?php
// be sure include path contains current directory
// to make sure samples work
ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path') . ':.');

// Load general helper classes for eBay SOAP API
require_once 'eBaySOAP.php';

// Load developer-specific configuration data from ini file
$config = parse_ini_file('ebay.ini', true);
$site = $config['settings']['site'];
$compatibilityLevel = $config['settings']['compatibilityLevel'];

$dev = $config[$site]['devId'];
$app = $config[$site]['appId'];
$cert = $config[$site]['cert'];
$token = $config[$site]['authToken'];
$location = $config[$site]['gatewaySOAP'];

// Create and configure session
$session = new eBaySession($dev, $app, $cert);
$session->token = $token;
$session->site = 1; // 100 = eBay Motors
$session->location = $location;

// Make a series of GetSearchResults API calls and print results
try {
    $client = new eBaySOAP($session);

    // Find 10 ipods and print their Titles
    $params = array('Version' => $compatibilityLevel, 
                    'Query' => 'ipod',
                    'Pagination' => array('EntriesPerPage' => 10),
                   );

    $results = $client->GetSearchResults($params);

    print "<pre>";
    //print_r($results);
    print "</pre>";

    foreach ($results->SearchResultItemArray as $item) {
        echo $item, "  <br>\n";
    }

    print "<p>---</p>\n";


    // Find 10 passenger vehicles (CategoryID 6001) within 10 miles of ZIP Code 95125
    // ordered by ascending distance
    $params = array('Version' => $compatibilityLevel, 
                    'Query' => '*',
                    'CategoryID' => 6001,
                    'ProximitySearch' => array('MaxDistance' => 10, 'PostalCode' => 95125),
                    'Pagination' => array('EntriesPerPage' => 10),
                    'Order' => 'SortByDistanceAsc',
                   );

    $results = $client->GetSearchResults($params);

    foreach ($results->SearchResultItemArray->SearchResultItem as $item) {
        print $item->Item->Title . " <br> \n";
    }

    print "<p>---</p>\n";

    // Find the count of all passenger vehicles (CategoryID 6001)
    $params = array('Version' => $compatibilityLevel, 
                    'Query' => '*',
                    'CategoryID' => 6001,
                    'TotalOnly' => true,
                   );
    $results = $client->GetSearchResults($params);
    $total = number_format($results->PaginationResult->TotalNumberOfEntries);
    print "There are $total passenger vehicles for sale on eBay Motors <br>\n";

} catch (SOAPFault $f) {
    print $f; // error handling
}

// Uncomment below to view SOAP envelopes
// print "Request: \n".$client->__getLastRequest() ."\n";
// print "Response: \n".$client->__getLastResponse()."\n";
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can u show us some code?

Comment: sure ill update the answer its just the exact code from here https://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/eBay/documentation-tools/code-sample/219177 expand view code on php example but ill also add above ;)

Comment: Most likely you are seeing this error because the call to `GetSearchResults` fails. Uncomment the line `//print_r($results);`, and check for possible error messages. Are you sure you've entered all details correctly in `ebay.ini`? Verify that also by dumping `$config`.

Comment: Hi Chris when i print results i get this error  Function ("GetSearchResults") is not a valid method for this service, so i am a bit confused could the service api calls have change. config seems fine and the service url gateway is there https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/wsapi

Comment: @user1503606: Getting that error means almost certainly that creating the client (`new eBaySOAP($session);`) failed - which is most likely because the details in `$session`, thus in `$config` are incorrect.

Comment: Ok thanks i am going to double check all my details

Comment: Hi all i have scrapped the version above and i have now used this tutorial which is working for me http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/Finding/HowTo/GettingStarted_PHP_NV_XML/GettingStarted_PHP_NV_XML.html

Comment: eBay got rid of GetSearchResults some time ago. It seems their examples are very much out of date. You can use the new finding API instead. http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar issue and I found this:

Important: GetSearchResults and GetCategoryListings are now deprecated and are no longer available. If you have applications that use the calls, please migrate your search functions to the Finding API. For new applications, please start with the Finding API.